# How can I add or remove tags when answering a question?

Tags: support, tags

How can I add or remove tags when answering a question?

Example:

I want to add the tag "openid" to the question [Autopromote users when they link an OpenID to their account?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14343703/1930997) .

My answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/14796406/731798 but I cannot find any possibility to edit-change-remove-add tags on the Stackoverflow GUI  when *answering* .

Did I overlook something, or is your interface indeed missing this important feature ?

Answer (score 3):

Tags are not part of an answer, nor can you edit question tags while answering. If you think the question is missing tags, you will have the edit the question separately.

Note: I have done just that.

Comment: Thank you!I just saw, that one also cna edit the question. Perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

Only questions have tags and for this reason, do not insert tags that are based on the answers: tags reflect the question's content.

Editing and answering are two different actions so, if you're answering, you're not editing and vice versa.

Comment: See the next answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167003/210783 : one can simply edit the original question, also when not being the original requester.  Thus http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167003/210783 is the wanted solution to my problem.

Comment: @Wikinaut That's exactly what I said. Our two answers state the same. You can edit any question, but usually you cannot do it while you're answering simultaneously... Unless you opened another tab in your browser, but what I mean is that asnwering and editing are two separate functions.